# Applying !important in <font color="#ff0000">

Tags: css, printing, summernote

I'm trying to print documents encoded using [summernote](https://summernote.org/).

There is no problem if the text has properties like this: `<span style="color:#ff0000 !important">Sample Text</span>` but in `summernote` they are using this code `<font color="#ff0000">Sample Text</font>`.

Comment: You can always put style on font too. Then you can put important there. (But if this is a new project, please don’t use font tag)

Comment: @Akxe font tag is automatically generated from summernote. thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Akxe for reminding me of putting style on the font tag.

I solved it by doing this

```
$('font').find().prevObject.each(function (i, v) {
            var color = "";
            $.each(this.attributes, function (i, v) {
                color = this.value;
            });
            $(this).attr('style', 'color:' + color + ' !important');
});
```

Unfortunately, I can't change `<font>` tag since the HTML codes are generated from `summernote` so what I did is First I find all font tags then get each property and append !important using attr.